# Are the results I get from anovas on subset of data valid?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, subset, anova

I am fairly new to stats & R, and wanted to know if the underlying code I was running was giving me valid results.

I have a dataset of subjects with different groups [4 groups] and conditions [2 conditions] and with repeated sampling of variable X across 4 trials and 3 tests (where each tests has 4 trials).

I want to analyze both within-subject information (e.g., difference in variable X across trials and test for a specific group in a specific condition). But also between-subject information (e.g., is there a difference in variable X during a specific test [Test 1] across all groups and conditions? is the change in variable X across tests [Test 1 and Test 2] different across groups and conditions?).

To do so, up until now I have always done the same thing which is as follows:

For example if i want to address the within-subject question (e.g., do subjects in Group1 in condition1 show a change of variable X across Tests?).

```
aov1 <-df %>%
    subset(., (Group =="Group_1" & Condition == 0)) %>%
    aov(variable_x ~ Test + Error(SubID/Trials), data=.)
```

with variations on what to subset to analyze the between-subject questions.

My question is: Can i cut my dataset like this and then run analyses on it? Does it violate any statistical principle?

Comment: If you are asking about statistical principles, then you should be asking your question at [stats.se] instead. That's the right site for statistical questions, not Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't seem specific to R or programming at all.

Comment: Oh I see, I will re-direct my question there. In terms of programming question, I was hoping someone with some more advanced knowledge on the underlying mechanics of the subset function from dplyr AND some knowledge of stats would be able to confirm that this was a correct usage of it. Although you are right it is more of a stats question. thank you!

Comment: Would be great if you could prepare a data example, e.g. based on [R built-in data set](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-built-in-data-sets).